# Resolve error with groupadd in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm building a PHP 7.4 container from Dockerfile  but i have a little problem with `groupadd` and rights.
The error message on build with `docker-compose build --no-cache` :

```
Step 41/46 : RUN groupadd -g ${SITE_GID} www
 ---> Running in ee94c83629f7
groupadd: invalid group ID 'www'
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c groupadd -g ${SITE_GID} www' returned a non-zero code: 3
```

Here's my docker-compose with PHP container :

```
services:
    # PHP
    php:
        build:
            context: docker/php7-fpm
            args:
                TIMEZONE: ${TIMEZONE}
                SITE_UID: ${SITE_UID}
                SITE_GID: ${SITE_GID}
        user: ${SITE_UID:-1000}:${SITE_GID:-1000}
        restart: unless-stopped
        hostname: php
        volumes:
            - ".:/var/www/symfony:rw"
            -  "./docker/php7-fpm/pool.d/application.conf:/opt/docker/etc/php/fpm/pool.d/application.conf"
            - "./docker/php7-fpm/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf"
            - "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent:ro"
        env_file:
          - ".env"
        environment:
            - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
        working_dir: /var/www/symfony
        networks:
          - dso_stack
```

Variables `${SITE_UID}` and `${SITE_GID}` are defined in .env file :

```
SITE_UID=XXXX # from command id -u
SITE_GID=YYYY # from command id -g
```

And my Dockerfile :

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=7.4
ARG TIMEZONE
ARG SITE_UID
ARG SITE_GID

FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm
USER root

# Installation of all dependencies..

# Add user for Symfony application
RUN groupadd -g ${SITE_GID} www
RUN useradd -u  ${SITE_UID} -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www/symfony
USER www

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

I'm not a docker jedi ^^ so i'm sure there are many little errors but i don't find exactly where. Thank you for answers :)

Comment: Try with `RUN groupadd -g ${SITE_GID} www && useradd -u ${SITE_UID} -g www -s /bin/sh www` and same...

Comment: same error with `RUN addgroup --system --gid ${SITE_GID} www && adduser --system --uid ${SITE_UID} --gid ${SITE_GID} www`

Comment: It's OK if i add hard values like this : `RUN addgroup --system --gid 1000 site && adduser --system --uid 1000 --gid 1000 site`. But in my container it's like this `I have no name!@php:`